How can i convert IEnumerable<SomeType> into single value properties
I have a third party dll. When I retrieve some data I get it back in the below format:
var getData = getSomeData();
var customers = getData.Customers;

customers has a type of IEnumerable<IGenericCustomer>, but has multiple entries inside it. Therefore inside customers in debug mode I see this:
[0] "customerName" ("Text")
[1] "customerId" ("Text")  
[2] "customerTitle" ("Text")
[3] "customerGender" ("Text")

Expanding each one gives more properties and information. In order to retrieve a value I currently can do something like
var customerName = customers
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Property == "customerName")
    .ToString();

Is there a way where I can just parse the IEnumerable<GenericCustomer> and it can add customerName, Id, Title, Gender to an object as single value properties other than using a foreach loop with an object and assigning each value to its own property (which if in future they add more properties it means I have to update this process?
I searched around for this but the ambiguity of my question didn't bring back a lot of results in what i'm trying to achieve so hoping someone has a nice simple example for me to follow.
Edit 1
This is what IGenericCustomer looks like (I changed this above to an Interface). There are loads of properties in a similar pattern. I used Property below to remain consistent with what I used above
public interface IGenericCustomer
{
    string Property {get;}
    ....
    ....
}


How does the GenericCustomer class look?

Can you convert it into a dictionary? var customerProperties = getData.Customers.ToDictionary(x => x.Property, x.Property.ToString());. You could then access it as customerProperties["customerName"]. It's at least less ugly. You could also map it into a custom class, but that you require you write the mapping code yourself, i don't think there's anything to do it for you, considering how specific it is.

Side thought: don't code like this - var getData = getSomeData(); Code like - IEnumerable<GenericCustomer> getData = getSomeData();

We can't guess what you're asking without knowing what GenericCustomer is. If that was a normal class, you'd already have single-valued properties. If you wanted to get the names of the customers you could just write customers.Select(c=>c.Name). I suspect that instead of an actual Customer or even a generic Customer, that's a Dictionary-like object or a dynamic object. Perhaps even something inheriting from DynamicObject

If GenericCustomer inherits from DynamicObject you can write customer.customerName.

Is this question about, how to view debugging information?

Ive updated my original question with more info requested

Why would it be so bad if you had to add an additional mapping in your for loop if they add a new property?

@Magnus my lead developer disapproves it and says it means the project has to be recompiled before it can go live so he would expect a 'better' way than foreach loops which is why im trying to see if there is a better way

In that case you would need to work with a dictionary instead.

The question is getting more vague. What you posted is more complicated than dynamic typing, which is available since C# 4. With a dynamic object, eg an ExpandoObject, you can type customer.Name directly or, if you cast to an IDictionary, you can use customer["Name"]

@Magnus Exactly. For a set of "properties" (in the general sense, i.e., data) of the same type -- here: string -- it makes more sense to have a dictionary indexed with a suitable enum. This makes loops without reflection trivial. One may even opt for an enum enumerating every field, regardless of type, and have a dictionary with objects or some general custom class in it; that is suitable for loops that perform operations that are valid for all of them, e.g. toString (to hold them in GUI widgets) or store them somewhere etc..

Of course, for the dictionary approach you need to be able to change the class.

You can declare a class with properties that exactly match names you find in the customers variable, but remove the` "customers" prefix. It's important they match exactly; any deviation will cause this to break:
public class Customer
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Gender {get;set;}
}

Now that you have this, you can use reflection to process your variable:
var getData = getSomeData();
var customerProperties = getData.Customers;
var customer = new Customer();
        
var ct = customer.GetType();
var reflectionProperties = ct.GetProperties();
    
foreach(var prop in customerProperties)
{   
    // .Substring(8) skips past the "customer" prefix
    var match = reflectionProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == prop.Property.Substring(8));
    if (match is object)
    {
        match.SetValue(customer, prop.ToString());
    }
}

// "customer" variable is now filled
Console.WriteLine($"Name: {customer.Name},\tId: {customer.Id},\tTitle: {customer.Title},\tGender: {customer.Gender}");

See it work here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/HIfGsw

I might also move this code to a constructor on my new Customer type that accepts an IEnumerable<IGenericCustomer>, or encapsulate it in its own mapping type.
And fwiw, IGenericCustomer should be named IGenericCustomerProperty, because the name you're currently using implies the type will hold ALL of the properties for a customer in a single instance.

Things get more complicated if you can have data for multiple customers in the same variable. In that situation, you'll need to know how to break apart your sequence.

I would skip any reflection attempt and do a for loop. Its not that difficult to add a case if a new property is added.
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(IEnumerable<GenericCustomer> customers)
    {
        foreach (var item in customers)
        {
            switch (item.Property)
            {
                case "customerName":
                    Name = item.ToString();
                    break;
                case "customerId":
                    Id = item.ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }            
    }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Gender { get; set; }
}


You can create a class to hold your data:
class Customer
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerTitle { get; set; }
    public string CustomerGender { get; set; }
}

Then create a generic mapper that uses reflection to set the properties:
static class GenericMapper<T> where T : new()
{
    public static T Map(IEnumerable<IGenericCustomer> genericCustomer)
    {
        var mapType = typeof(T);
        T instance = new();
        foreach(var property in mapType.GetProperties())
        {
            var genericValue = genericCustomer.FirstOrDefault(x => property.Name.Equals(x.Property, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (genericValue != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(instance, genericValue.ToString());
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

Then use it as:
var customer = GenericMapper<Customer>.Map(getData.Customers);

Console.WriteLine(customer.CustomerId);
Console.WriteLine(customer.CustomerName);
Console.WriteLine(customer.CustomerTitle);
Console.WriteLine(customer.CustomerGender);

Without you being more specific with your class definition, I can't help you any further, but this should give you a baseline.
